# blogger menu not showing on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

blogger blog's menu doesn't show on mobile phones, and it produces many blank white lines when shown on mobile phone. But it works correctly on computer screen. What is wrong with the code?

This is the link of blog : [My Blog](https://dailylekhaari.com)

Menu = Home | Contact Us | About Us | پاکستان | .....

Theme's Menu Code:

```
<!-- main menu -->
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>



<ul>
  <li><a class='active' href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com'>Home</a> </li>
  <li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/p/contact-us.html'>Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/p/about.html'>About Us</a></li>

  <li><h1 style='     padding: 14px 16px;     padding-top: 14px;     padding-right: 16px;     padding-bottom: 0px;     padding-left: 16px; '><font color='white'>*   </font></h1></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%D9%BE%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86'>پاکستان</a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%85%DB%8C'>بین الاقوامی</a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85'>اسلام </a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%86%D8%B3%20%D9%88%20%D9%B9%DB%8C%DA%A9%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AC%DB%8C'>سائنس ٹیکنالوجی</a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%DA%A9%DA%BE%DB%8C%D9%84'>کھیل</a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B2'>کالمز</a></li>
<li><a href='https://www.dailylekhaari.com/search/label/%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA'>سیاست</a></li>

</ul>



<!-- main menu end -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove HTML comments, remove `<!-- hamara main menu` and `hamara main menu end -->`

[image]

To show menu on mobile add this to CSS

```
.header-wrap ul { overflow: visible !important }
```

Comment: I removed the tags but it still not showing on mobile phone

Comment: Ok, you have to make overflow: visible; to ul element,  see answer update

Answer (score 1):

It's caused because you have not specified float or simply you can use clearfix hack.

Just add Clearfix after `headerwrap`.

```
<div id="header-wrap"> ... </div>
<!-- This clearfix used for clearing floats between elements -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```